# EventHubConsumerClient subscribe method not working with Azure blob container in AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, azure-blob-storage, azure-eventhub

I'm using the Node JS EventHubConsumerClient to read events from an EventHub hosted in a third party account, using this guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-node-get-started-send

I am also using a blob storage container that is hosted in my own Azure account to maintain the checkpoint of what the last read event was, the blob storage client is passed to the `EventHubConsumerClient` as an argument.

When I run the application locally it is able to successfully read from the EventHub and use the blob storage container for checkpointing. However, when I deploy this application to AWS and use it within a Lambda I receive this error upon invoking the `subscribe` method on the consumer client:

`Method get TypedArray.prototype.length called on incompatible receiver [object Object]`

I can't find any documentation online related to EventHub to help identify the root cause of this issue and i'm not sure how to debug this. I have confirmed that the blob storage is being successfully connected to from AWS via the logs.

Has anyone encountered this issue?

Code for creating blob checkpoint store:

```
const createCheckpointStore = async (
  blobStorageUrl: string,
  accountName: string,
  accountKey: string
): Promise<BlobCheckpointStore> => {
  const credentials = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey)
  const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(blobStorageUrl, credentials)

  const blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(
    'event-hub-checkpoint'
  )

  const iter = blobContainerClient.listBlobsFlat()
  for await (const item of iter) {
    console.log(`\tBlobItem: name - ${item.name}`)
    const blockBlobClient = blobContainerClient.getBlockBlobClient(item.name)
    const meta = (await blockBlobClient.getProperties()).metadata
    console.log(meta)
  }

  return new BlobCheckpointStore(blobContainerClient)
}
```

Code for creating the event hub consumer client:

```
const createEventHubConsumerClient = async () => {
  try {
    const accountName = await getSecretFromEnvVariable(
      'BLOB_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME'
    )
    const accountKey = await getSecretFromEnvVariable(
      'BLOB_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY'
    )

    const checkpointStore = await createCheckpointStore(
      getEnvironmentVariable('BLOB_STORAGE_URL'),
      accountName,
      accountKey
    )
    const consumerGroup = '$Default'
    const eventHubConnectionString = getEnvironmentVariable(
      'EXPORT_EVENT_HUB_CONNECTION_STRING'
    )
    const eventHubName = 'export'

    return new EventHubConsumerClient(
      consumerGroup,
      eventHubConnectionString,
      eventHubName,
      checkpointStore
    )
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('error creating eventhub consumer client', error)
    throw error
  }
}
```

Read events method code:

```
const getEvents = async () => {
  const consumerClient = await createEventHubConsumerClient()
  try {
    await new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
      const subscription: Subscription = consumerClient.subscribe(
        {
          processEvents: async (events, context) => {
            console.log('received events', events)
            await asyncForEach(events, async (event: ReceivedEventData) => {
              const processedEntities = extractEntitiesFromEventHubEvent(event)
              await asyncForEach(
                processedEntities,
                async (entity: any) => {
                  try {
                    console.log(entity)
                  } catch (err) {
                    throw new Error(err)
                  }
                }
              )
              await context.updateCheckpoint(events[events.length - 1])
            })
          },
          processError: async err => {
            console.error('error encountered', err)
            await subscription.close()
            await consumerClient.close()
            console.error('error processing events', err)
            reject(new Error('error processing events'))
          },
        },
        {
          startPosition: earliestEventPosition,
          maxBatchSize: 100,
          maxWaitTimeInSeconds: 5,
        }
      )
    })
  } catch (err) {
    // log error here that event hub consume failed
    console.error('error encountered', err)
    throw new Error(err)
  }
}
```

Comment: Any code? There's nothing here to go based off on.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary sorry have added the code as an edit, it fails as soon as i call the subscribe method but only when deployed to Lambda, locally it all works successfully and logs the events + checkpoints correctly.